# How to save multiple upload file to the database

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I have a problem to save multiple upload file to the database. i use drag and drop multiple upload file with html 5. for example, i want to save 2 image in the 1 table but different row. so, this is my simple structure table database and web.

table database

```
name, 'int', '25'.
image1, 'var', '100'.
image2, 'var', '100'.
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="multiupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var config = {
// Valid file formats
support : "image/jpg,image/png,image/bmp,image/jpeg,image/gif",
form: "demoFiler", // Form ID
dragArea: "dragAndDropFiles", // Upload Area ID
uploadUrl: "upload.php" // Server side file url
}
//Initiate file uploader.
$(document).ready(function()
{
initMultiUploader(config);
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

 <div id="dragAndDropFiles" class="uploadArea">
<h1>Drop Images Here</h1>
</div>
<form name="demoFiler" id="demoFiler" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="multiUpload" id="multiUpload" multiple />
<input type="submit" name="submitHandler" id="submitHandler" value="Upload" />
</form>
<div class="progressBar">
<div class="status"></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name']))
            {
                echo($_POST['index']); // to validate
            }
        exit;
    }
?>
```

So, what i must to do for modify upload.php script?? thank's for you're advice..

Answer (score 0):

You can use your form like this :

First you need to change your form select into: `name="multiUpload[]"`

```
$arr = $_GET['multiUpload'];

foreach($arr as $option) {
    echo $option."<br>"; //Do whatever you want.
}
```